# Мне нужно получить категорию в discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord, discord.py

Мне нужно чтобы новый канал создавался в той же категории, где происходит bot.event.
У меня create_text_channel категорию по какой то причине указывает none и мне нужно как то получить категорию, в документации я не нашел,уже очень долго не могу решить эту проблему.

Мой код:

```
ticket_channel = await payload.member.guild.create_text_channel('cool-channel')
```

Что выводит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если что вот фулл bot.event:

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    print(discord.CategoryChannel.category)
    if payload.message_id == 784376584824029245:
        if payload.emoji.id == 699160204205621299:
            ticket_channel = await payload.member.guild.create_text_channel(name='cool-channel)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно месяц назад шлюз дискорда был обновлен и теперь для того чтобы работать с объектами пользователей, а также с объектами серверов нужно выдавать намерения (`intents`). У вас проблема как раз таки в том, что скорее всего **вы не выдали боту необходимые намерения**. Чтобы их выдать, вам нужно при инициализации бота, помимо префикса указать также намерения.

**Выдаем боту намерения при объявлении:**

```
# если у вас discord.Client()
bot = discord.Client(intents = discord.Intents.all())

# если у вас commands.Bot()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents = discord.Intents.all())
```

---

**Если проблема осталась**, то попробуйте включить два пункта на странице вашего бота. Для этого зайдите в [раздел приложений](https://discord.com/developers/applications) и выберите вашего бота. Затем, слева, на вкладке "Bot"

[image: Бот]

Включите параметры `PRESENCE INTENT` и `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо, вы были правы, но помимо этого я тут нарыл ,что категория - всего лишь другой тип канала. Получить объект категории можно также как и любого другого канала <3